# Search history in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elastic-stack, elk

Is there any way to check search history in elasticsearch?
I'm wondering how seek someone responsible for data leakage in organization if it happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the search History in Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982039/how-to-get-the-search-history-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Better to enable logs in elasticsearch. Elasticsearch gives slow log features you use this with least threshold